# Add an Icon to the Top Bar using AppIndicator3

Tags: gnome, icons, indicator

I want to create a time counter that gets added to the top bar in Ubuntu (GNOME Shell 42.9).

I am trying to add an icon first, but it doesn't get added. I also installed all necessary dependencies and restarted the computer.

```
import signal
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('AppIndicator3', '0.1')
from gi.repository import Gtk, AppIndicator3, GLib

APPINDICATOR_ID = 'custom_indicator'
CUSTOM_ICON_PATH = '/home/afranz/Desktop/ActiveTime/activity_counter_app/icon.svg'

class CustomIndicator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.indicator = AppIndicator3.Indicator.new(
            APPINDICATOR_ID, CUSTOM_ICON_PATH, AppIndicator3.IndicatorCategory.APPLICATION_STATUS
        )
        self.indicator.set_status(AppIndicator3.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)

    def run(self):
        Gtk.main()

def main():
    gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
    gi.require_version('AppIndicator3', '0.1')
    
    app = CustomIndicator()
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)  # Allow Ctrl+C to exit the application
    app.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am also not getting any error when running this.

The path is correct, I am using Python 3.10.12 and Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.

I also enabled [this GNOME extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/615/appindicator-support/) (since legacy tray icons seem to be disabled by default with modern GNOME versions).

Also, I am not constrained to use AppIndicator for any reason, it's just the common solution I saw while researching online about how to "add stuff to the top bar in Ubuntu".